# Understanding Numpy's `multivariate_normal` method

Tags: python, numpy, random, gaussian

I wish to generate samples from a multivariate Gaussian distribution with `0` mean and a very low standard deviation (`0.001`). But when I plot the resultant samples, I am confused about their range.

If we look at a random sample generated from a standard Gaussian distribution, it looks fine. A good proportion of samples lie within the (-1, +1) boundary on both axes (the ideal should be 66%?). Besides, all the samples lie in the range of (-3, +3) which seems fine.

```
mean = np.array([0., 0.])
cov1 = np.array([[1., 0.], [0., 1.]])
size = 100

vals1 = np.random.multivariate_normal(mean, cov1, size)
plt.scatter(vals1[:, 0], vals1[:, 1])
```

[image: Samples from standard Gaussian distribution]

Now when I reduce the standard deviation to `0.001`, I expect the samples to be in the range `(-0.003, 0.003)` but they are an order of magnitude higher. I see them lie in the range `(-0.06, 0.06)`.

```
cov2 = np.array([[0.001, 0.], [0., 0.001]])

vals2 = np.random.multivariate_normal(mean, cov2, size)
plt.scatter(vals2[:, 0], vals2[:, 1])
```

[image: Samples from Gaussian distribution with std=0.001]

I suppose there is something wrong with the way I am interpreting the range of samples from a multivariate Gaussian. Can anyone help me make sense of these results? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a covariance matrix is diagonal, its diagonal entries are the *variances* (σ^2) of each variable. So when you have

```py
cov2 = np.array([[0.001, 0.], [0., 0.001]])
```

you are really choosing the standard deviation (σ) in each variable to be sqrt(0.001) = 0.03162277660168379.

Comment: Yes, I should have seen that. Thanks!